# Recursively finding all prime numbers up to a given number (Project Euler 10) gives StackOverflow Error

Tags: java

I am trying to implement a recursive algorithm to find all the prime number up to the given number to solve Project Euler problem 10.

Whenever I try this for large numbers I get a `StackOverflowError: null`.

My code is:

```
public long sumOfPrimes(long num,  long start){
    if(start>num)
        return 0;
    else{
        boolean isPrime = true;
        for(long i=2; i<start; i++){
            if(start%i==0)
                isPrime = false;
        }
        if(isPrime && start>=2)
            return start+sumOfPrimes(num, start+1);
        else
            return sumOfPrimes(num, start+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you go for an iterative implementation ? There is a simple way to do it and it takes 3 seconds to compute (quite long but sufficient for this problem).

Comment: What is `isPrime` actually meant to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You recurse for every number between `start` and `num`. When the difference is too great, you recurse *too often* and you get the StackOverflowError.

Try recursing only when you actually get to a prime to improve your results. (i.e. loop through the numbers between `start` and `num` until isPrime = true.